# creating IIS 7 sub domains

Tags: windows, iis-7

I have IIS set and is serving pages correctly on www.site.com. I have a sub directory and can access this using www.site.com/sub. I want to address it as www.sub.site.com. I have set up A records for site.com, www.site.com, www.sub.site.com all pointing to the same server.

I set up binding on default web site for www.sub.site.com but if I try and access this through a browser I get an internal server error 500. www.sub.site.com/sub does however work. This is my first time setting up IIS server for general use and I am now lost. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put www in front of your sub site. you should have something like this instead :

www.example.com
subsite.example.com

if you want to add /sub at the end of www.example.com I would either have a link on my main page to go to that URL or have default site redirect to that URL. So your A record is going to be subsite A in site.com for subsite.site.com.